# How do I make an audio player with the Spotify Web API?

Tags: javascript, json, api, audio, spotify

I was trying to make an audio player by starting with a play button. In my HTMl code i made a button:

```
<a href="#" id="play" alt="animate" class="btnstyle">Play</a>
```

Then I used this code to make it play a song, but it doesnt seem to work.

```
document.getElementById('play').addEventListener('click', function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/play',
    type: 'PUT',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
    },
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        "uris": ["spotify:track:"] + apiData.item.id,
        "position_ms": apiData.progress_ms
    })
  });
});
```

apiData.item.id refers to the id of the currently playing track
apiData.progress_ms refers to the progress in milliseconds of currently playing track.

When I run my code and click on the play button, nothing happens. I don't know what I did wrong.

But I tried making a pause button by first making a button with an id called 'pause'. Then I did the following:

```
document.getElementById('pause').addEventListener('click', function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/pause',
    type: 'PUT',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
    },
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify({
      "uris": ["spotify:track:"] + apiData.item.id,
      "position_ms": apiData.progress_ms
    })
  });
});
```

This is actually working! But I don't understand why the play button doesn't work and the pause button does. 
Here is the documentation I used for both buttons:
https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/player/start-a-users-playback/
https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/player/pause-a-users-playback/

For the play button I got this error in the console log:
[error 400](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqTtP.jpg)

Can somebody help me out?

Comment: a 400 error is a bad request, so in a RESTful API design it usually indicates that in some way your request did not meet the API's expectation. Look in the network tab of your browser to a) check what your request actually looked like and whether it's what you expected, and is compliant with the documentation, and b) check to see if the response from the server contains any more information about what the mistake actually was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr: Working snippets at the bottom of this answer!**

---

The `uris` field takes an array containing Spotify uris. This `"uris": ["spotify:track:"] + apiData.item.id` doesn't resolve to an array but to a string which is not what the endpoint awaits. Using `` [`spotify:track:${id}`] `` will work therefore.

[This](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PygRrv) snippet shows the difference between the two.

```
console.log(["spotify:track:"] + id);
// Output with id = 1234: "spotify:track:1234" -> String

console.log([`spotify:track:${id}`]);
// Output with id = 1234: ["spotify:track:1234"] -> Array of strings
```

---

The reason the stop button works is that Spotify's `pause` endpoint doesn't use any of the data you passed in. The `pause` endpoint only has one optional query parameter called `device_id`. The data you passed along with it just gets ignored therefore. So the Ajax call for pause can be simplified as seen in the following snippets.

---

Here are two working snippets given that an access token is used that has the `user-modify-playback-state` scope authorized.

**Play**

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/play',
  type: 'PUT',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
  },
  dataType: "json",
  contentType: "application/json",
  data: JSON.stringify({
    "uris": [`spotify:track:${apiData.item.id}`],
    "position_ms": apiData.progress_ms
  })
});
```

**Pause**

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/pause',
  type: 'PUT',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
  }
});
```